# Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined

Tags: sencha-touch

HI im getting this error after executing my code. It says "Uncaught typeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined".Im trying to display a list using my defined model named "model.login" and a store with dummy data.

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true,
paths:{
    'model' : 'app/model',
    'store' : 'app/store'
}

});
Ext.application({
    name: 'GS',
    launch: function(){
        var myStore = null;
        Ext.require('model.login', function(){
            var login = Ext.create('model.login');
            myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
                model: login,
                data:[
                      {id:'09803' , issued_at: 'thisurl', instance_url:'https', signature:'token', access_token:'ser'}
                      ]
            });
        });
        this.viewport = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            items:[
                   {
                       xtype: 'list',
                       itemTpl: '{id}',
                       store: myStore
                   }
                   ]
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to create the viewport is happening before `model.login` is loaded and your store is created. Move the code to create the viewport into the callback for your `Ext.require`.

Also, when passing a model into the store, you pass the model constructor, not an instance of it.

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'GS',
  launch: function(){
    this.viewport = 
    var me = this;
    Ext.require('model.login', function(){                
      myStore = new Ext.data.Store({;

      me.viewport = new Ext.Panel({
        fullscreen: true,
        // You can pass a single item into item
        items:{
          xtype: 'list',
          itemTpl: '{id}',
          store: myStore
        }
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Note that there's a better way to do this, you can tell the application what models to load and inline some of your calls to make it easier to read

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'GS',
  models: 'login', // looks in GS.model.login
  launch: function(){
    me.viewport = new Ext.Panel({
      fullscreen: true,
      // You can pass a single item into item
      items:{
        xtype: 'list',
        itemTpl: '{id}',
        store: {
          model: 'model.login', // or GS.model.login without quotes
          data:[              
            {id:'09803' , issued_at: 'thisurl', instance_url:'https', signature:'token', access_token:'ser'}]
          }
       }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I moved the code like you suggested but i still get the same error ,Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isModel' of undefined.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to make the error go away but the page is blank now.

Comment: @KevinMorfin You should only ask one question per post, that makes the post as useful as possible to others reading the site. You should ask a new question for the new problem. The question as asked has been answered and is already helpful for others that may have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

For me it was misnamed column in sql.